# Regular expression for range checking for non ASCII characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to split the characters that are not in ASCII format i.e UTF-8.
I wrote this line of code

```
result = string.scan(/[\x0600-\x06ff]/)
```

And somehow it is not working, and give error

```
"empty range in char class : /[\x0600-\x06ff]/".
```

I just want to check if a character falls in range of regular expression. If so,  then split it out.

Comment: I can't use it because i have to **check if character falls in given range or not**. If yes then split it.

Comment: My task is not to check every non-ascii character.
Range I want to check is given in question 0600-06ff

Answer (score 6):

Ruby doesn't support Unicode tokens in it's implementation of regex <sup>(or my RegexBuddy is telling me lies)</sup>

If I try `\u0000` I get an error that says it is not supported.
If your version of Ruby does support it, the range is `[\u0000-\uFFFF]`

You could try using the POSIX class `[^[:ascii:]]` to match everything non-ASCII.
You could also try `[^\x00-\xFF]` to match everything which does not have a decimal value of 0-255.

Comment: `\uHHHH` is used to specify Unicode by hex value but +1 for `:ascii:`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're using `\x` incorrectly. `\xHH` specifies the byte that is `HH` in hexadecimal. That means that `\x0600` is actually `\x06`, `0`, and `0` and your whole character class looks like (with spaces to separate the parts):

```
\x06 0 0-\x06 f f
```

and the only range is `0-\x06` and that's not what you want. If you want to specify Unicode by hex value, then you want to use `\u`:

```
/[\u0600-\u06ff]/
```

Furthermore, your range misses a lot of non-ASCII values (such as `'µ'` which is `\u00b5`), you'd be better off using [Vasili's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22137989/479863) `/[^[:ascii:]]/` POSIX named character class or `/[^\p{ASCII}]/`.

Comment: i want this to calculate count of unicode characters
But this regular expression isn't working, it always goes in else part. Can you spot the problem.
`if unicode.match(/[\u0600-\u06ff]/)
unicodeChars += 1
else
asciiChars += 1
end`

Comment: What does `unicode` look like? Why not use Vasili's `[^[:ascii:]]` regex instead? Your 0x0600 to 0x06ff range misses a fair bit (such as `'µ'` which is `\u00b5`.

Comment: In above code **unicode has 4 digit hex number**, and the reason i am not using [^[:ascii:]] is i have to check how much of document is in **urdu** and how much of it is english. So in order to check i have to compare each character within given range. Beacuse there is alot of other unicode characters. And if i use [^[:ascii:]] as regular expression then other unicode characters other than urdu 'll also be making their existance in count. So **urdu** characters unicode range is from 0600-06ff

Comment: I still don't know what exactly your `unicode` string looks like so I can't say any more. `"\u0600".match(/[\u0600-\u06ff]/)` works as expected for me.